# Does it Make Sense to Use the Variable of Integration as a Bound?

Tags: integration

I can't for the life of me seem to decide if using the variable of integration as a bound makes sense. For instance, integrating $y=x$ from $0$ to $x$. I don't *think* it does… But I'm not sure.

Comment: Letters/variables in mathematical expressions are either “bound” or “free.” Free variables are those you **can** “plug in a value” for. Bound variables are those you **can’t**. You can rename a bound variable without changing the meaning of the mathematics. $\int_0^x{x\,dx}$ probably means $\int_0^\color{purple}{x}{\color{red}{x}\,d\color{red}{x}}$. There is one $x$, the red one, that’s bound, and an unrelated one, the purple one, that’s free. It’s confusing, but possible to make sense out of, because the upper limit of a single integral can’t be bound to the “variable of integration.”

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533541/integral-notation-confusion-x-vs-t?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to use a dummy variable in the integrand itself. For example, we could write $$\int_0^x{t\,dt}=\frac{x^2}{2}$$ It does not really make sense to write something like $$\int_0^x{x\,dx}$$  because $x$ is a variable which is changing as the integral is computed. $x$ starts at $0$ and moves toward... toward $x$? That said, I think most people would agree that the value of that integral should be considered as $x^2/2$. Just note that the $x$ in the integral bound and the $x$'s in the integrand are technically different.

Perhaps it will be illumating to consider the discrete analogue. What would $$\sum_{n=0}^n{n}$$ mean?

Comment: Well that's what I meant, it makes no sense if they are the same, right?

Comment: Also, look what happens when $x=2$: $\int_0^2{2\,d2}$... madness!